# Tsung - How to send array or object in request parameters?

Tags: php, load-testing, tsung

I need to send object like php

```
$obj = [
        array('id' => '111');
    ];
```

as POST request parameter.
I tried to use

```
[{struct,[{<<"id">>,<<"111">>},{<<"id">>, <<"222">>}]}]

[{struct,[{&quot;id&quot;,&quot;111&quot;}]}]

[{struct,[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;111&quot;}]}]

[{struct,[{&quot;id&quot;=>&quot;111&quot;}]}]

[[{&quot;id&quot;,&quot;111&quot;}]]

[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;111&quot;}]

[{&quot;id&quot;=>&quot;111&quot;}]
```

but it is wrong. 
I tried to replace "  by `&quot;` but it's wrong too. 
I don't find any examples in user manual about work with array or object. Does anyone faced with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Build a query string using square brackets then URL encode it.

Example query string:

`someArray[someindex_1][name]=blah&someArray[someindex_1][id]=123&someArray[someindex_2][name]=bah blah&someArray[someindex_2][id]=456`

send the encoded string as the body of the post request. This should result in an array on the server like this:

```
print_r($_POST['someArray']);

// array(
// "someindex_1" => array(
//    "name" => "blah"
//    "id" => 123
//  )
//  "someindex_2" => array(
//    "name" => "blah blah"
//    "id" => 456
//  )
//);
```

Comment: But how to do it correctly in the Tsung session? Tsung request describes in xml as <http url='exampleurl' version='1.1'  contents=''" content_type='application/json;charset=utf-8' method='POST'></http>

Answer (score 0):

You can send an array in a POST request using the HTML element name with the square brackets "[]". An example is show below:

```
<input type="text" name="countries[]" value="Nigeria">
<input type="text" name="countries[]" value="Ghana">
```

Then in your PHP code, you can retrieve the values this way:

```
$countries = $_POST['countries']; //$countries is now an array of POST-ed countries
var_dump($countries);
```

But if what you want to send across is an Object, then you have to serialize it. You can use the code below:

```
$obj = get_an_object_somehow();
$encoded_obj = base64_encode(serialize($obj));
```

Then in your HTML form:

```
<input type="text" name="myObj" value="$encoded_obj">
```

Finally, in your form processing script, you can unserialize it as follows:

```
$decoded_obj = unserialize(base64_decode($obj));//get back original object
var_dump($decoded_obj);
```

Comment: If you do it on the php it`s simple, but I need to pass it in Tsung request